# Clean up CREATE TABLE column layout

Tags: sql, perl, code-formatting

I've got a series of sql scripts that look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE table_one
(
    column_one            int   not null,
    column_two    varchar(100)               not null,
    column_three_four_five int,
    column_six    decimal(16,4) null,
    PRIMARY KEY ( column_one, column_three_four_five)
);
```

I'd like to clean up the layout to be easier to scan, something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE table_one
(
    column_one             int          not null,
    column_two             varchar(100) not null,
    column_three_four_five int,
    column_six             decimal(16,4)     null,
    PRIMARY KEY
    (
        column_one,
        column_three_four_five
    )
);
```

The exact layout is less important than being able to create a clean look to improve readability. (read: please don't flame the formatting itself) -grin-

What would be a good way to script this (I'm looking at you, Perl gods...)?

Comment: You know, phrases like "Perl gods" (with a small *g* no less), "gurus", "hackers" begin to lose their originality(!) after a while.

Comment: just one question are those tabulations and space or only one of the 2 ?

Comment: @Prix: spaces, to keep it simple. I'm not looking for fancy, just clean :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmmmm well can't say it will work for all your files but something like this would do the job ...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; 
use warnings;

my $default_padding = 30;
my $my_file = 'data.sql';
my $my_new_file = 'data_new.sql';

open (my $fh, '<', $my_file) or die $!;
my @sql = <$fh>;
close($fh);

open (my $fhsave, '>>', $my_new_file) or die $!;
foreach my $line (@sql) {
    print $fhsave "$line" if ($line !~ /^\s+/);
    $line =~ s/\s+/ /ig;
    print $fhsave sprintf("   %-*s %s\n", $default_padding, $1, $2) if ($line =~ /^\s+(.+?)\s+(.+)/);
}
close ($fhsave);
```

sample file data.sql

```
CREATE TABLE table_one
(
    column_one            int   not null,
    column_two    varchar(100)               not null,
    column_three_four_five int,
    column_six    decimal(16,4) null
);
```

output:

```
CREATE TABLE table_one
(
   column_one                     int not null, 
   column_two                     varchar(100) not null, 
   column_three_four_five         int, 
   column_six                     decimal(16,4) null 
);
```

Comment: Thanks, Prix!  That's it.  Simple, clean, just what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried either one, but CPAN has [SQL::Beautify](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?SQL::Beautify) and [SQL::QueryBuilder::Pretty](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?SQL::QueryBuilder::Pretty).

Comment: Those are nice but the second one does not know what the CREATE TABLE is and will mess it up and the first one does format very well but has some problems with new lines and parenthesis. They seem to be more suitable for select,delete,update queries instead.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm

Not a script.  But I don't want to code anything right now.

For stuff like this in any language look for formatters or the word 'pretty' for prebuilt junk.

Comment: great site.  Would be groovy, but I've inherited about 300 of these scripts in various states of nasty.  thanks for the link, though.